# open, mmap pcie path CM4

Tags: pci

I have a problem finding the correct path to use for open and then mmap. In another linux system I found the device at "/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/resource0" but what should the path be for the raspberry CM4? I have checked that the device is linked by lspci but are there any easy way to locate the correct path to use?

Answer (score 1):

### It is the same?

In my experience the path should be the same up to /sys/bus/pci/devices/. Then its the id that lspci tells you. So I dont know where this would be going wrong.

### Identifying a device

I might misunderstand your question. If you need an easy way to identify a device then one thing you can do is iterate over all folders in devices, and then reading something that can identify your device like "device" and "vendor". ([basically this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010671/how-to-get-vendor-id-and-device-id-of-all-pci-devices))

Though there are probably better ways of doing this.

### Enabling mmapped interfacing

On a sidenode, on Raspbian you might need to enable memory mapped interfacing using
`setpci -s <BUS_ADDR> COMMAND=0x02`